# Loading String from plist to UILabel (Swift)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, plist

I am now to swift and I want to load different strings into different uilabel. 
I am having the Plist like this:

[image]

Code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var Label: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var Label2: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var Label3: UILabel!

var Data = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Property", ofType: "plist")
    let dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path!)

    Data = dict!.objectForKey("Time") as! [String]


    //Code for Label 1 -3
}
```

What code I can use to get the items from plist accordingly e.g. Items 0 to Label1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Label.text = Data[0] // Items 0 to Label1
Label2.text = Data[1] // Items 1 to Label2
Label3.text = Data[2] // Items 2 to Label3
```

Comment: Thanks for you quick answer.